# posting as a page not as an individual with facebook php sdk 5.0.0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I've searched all over for this, the 'answers' I got were outdated. Anytime I run the script it posts the message with my profile to the facebook page even though I have admin permissions.
This is the code I'm using

```
<?
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';
session_start();

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '',
'app_secret' => '',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
]);
$page_id="";
$accessToken='Access token I got from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/';


// Sets the default fallback access token so we don't have to pass it to each request
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken('');

try {
  $response = $fb->get('/me');
  $userNode = $response->getGraphPage();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
// When Graph returns an error
 echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

echo 'Logged in as ' . $userNode->getName();



?>
```

Comment: What is your script supposed to do (instead of posting a message with your profile)?

Comment: It's supposed to post **as the page**. i.e Like I went to the page and posted something as supposed to posting like a visitor(someone who doesn't have administrative priviledges) on the page. The post's supposed to be in the page's name, not mine.

Comment: Use a page access token and post using that

Comment: I've not gotten how to get a page access token. The tutorials I saw were outdated. Can you provide a code snippet pls?

Comment: Documentation? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Comment: I've seen that page and I don't get how to use the "GET /{user-id}/accounts" I tried $fb->get($userid/accounts) but it didn't work.